# How can control print pop window with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

it is my code, i want to click print cancel then my script not execute i will click ok then this code will run. please give me positive feedback.

```
(function() {

var afterPrint = function() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log('Responce',this.responseText);  
        //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("POST", "<?php echo site_url('AppsCtr/updatePrintLog');?>", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("COMP_CODE=<?php echo $session_company_name;?>&UIL_DOC_NO=<?php echo $head[0]['OPH_TXN_CODE'].'-'.$head[0]['OPH_TXN_NO'];?>&UIL_SYS_ID=<?php echo $head[0]['OPH_SYS_ID'];?>&ACTION=Print&DETAILS="); 

};

// supported by Chrome 9+ and Safari 5.1+
if (window.matchMedia) {
    var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
    mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
        if (mql.matches) {
            beforePrint();
        } else {
            afterPrint();
        }
    });
}

// supported by IE 5+ and FireFox 6+
window.onafterprint = afterPrint;
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your question is little bit bad formatted, i think you want to something when click on ok, and something diferent when click in cancel, well if is that, i suggest to you, use a function with diferent id for example:

```
<button id="ok" onclick="dosomething(this.id);"></button>
<button id="cancel" onclick="dosomething(this.id);"></button>

<script>
// this is the most important, for separate the diferent actions //
function dosomething(a) {
    if (a === "ok") {
       // your code of the popup ok //
    }
    if (a === "cancel") {
       // the code of the popup cancel //
    }
}
</script>
```